# android Menu search button

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I am trying to put a search button on action bar. And  i have a list on the screen, on searching any text list will be refreshed and display that text data on the same screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
     return true;
}
```

On click search button expends and soft keyboard show search button to search.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.search:
            // startSearchActivity();
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dddddd " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sssssss " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but search button of softkeyboard is not showing any action. Please tell me whats wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

implement **setOnQueryTextListener** in **onCreateOptionsMenu** instead of **onOptionsItemSelected**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dddddd " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sssssss " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```